# command line grep dropping tabs / truncating data / concatenating data

Tags: bash, command-line, grep

I have recently been programmatically processing a large data file ([link](http://www.broadinstitute.org/ccle/downloadFile/DefaultSystemRoot/exp_10/ds_21/CCLE_Expression_Entrez_2012-10-18.res?downloadff=true&fileId=6805)) and decided to run a few grep commands from the terminal to pull specific rows and spot check that my program was processing the data properly. 
The file that I performed this grep on is tab delimited and contains gene expression data. Each row contains a gene name followed by several columns of data.
I performed the following grep command in terminal:

```
grep IRX3 rma_CCLE_Expression_Entrez_2012-10-18.res
```

Here "IRX3" is a gene name and rma_CCLE... is the file name.

This command pulled the correct row from the file, but dropped several tabs and deleted a few columns as well (there are ~2000 columns, only the 10s are shown below):

> IRX3  79191_at    10.27105    P   9.802959    P   9.155978    P   3.944805    A   10.86381    P   11.219  P   8.894276    P   9.498839    P   10.97627    P   5.493518    A   10.12431    P   5.596724    P   11.97915    P   5.626475    A   8.586957    P   8.188652    P   11.46542    P   8.968493    P   8.015925    P   7.050888    P   10.34178    P   8.417319    P   8.865884    P   8.221919    P   6.207358    P   11.76088    P   7.162497    P   9.491752    P   4.784088    A   8.938905    P   5.123149    A   11.85545    P   10.13062    P   9.163952    P   5.67286 P   6.959234    P   12.05033    P   8.826333    P   5.065222    **A 4.791684    8.042779**  P   10.33864    P   7.781193    P   8.982947    P   4.262702    A   8.10075 P   5.307268    A   8.95283 P   10.13345    P   10.00931    P   8.48634 P   9.159968    P   8.849957    P   4.47576....

Notice the bold text, there should be a letter between these 2 values (either a "A" a "P"), matching the pattern of the other columns. Why is grep truncating this data? I was pulling my hair out thinking that the integrity of the source data was to blame, but when I iterate over the file programmatically via a Perl script I wrote, the data was fine (i.e. there was a letter between the 2 indicated values).

What gives?

Comment: I assume you're redirecting output to a file. But if you're letting the output flow to the screen, then I would think that what you're seeing is a failing of the terminal software when asked to display an oversized line. So `grep IRX3 file> outFile` and see if your data is then correctly formatted. ELSE another possibility is that your source has put some cntrl-chars in the output stream. Search S.O. for `od -c`. there have been numerous discussions about debugging funky data (yes, I know it works in perl, so if you don't have time to debug, continue using perl?) Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks @shellter, you're completely correct! The issue was printing to the screen -- directing the output to a file solved the issue. Weird that the terminal software in OS X would have such a bug, but nevertheless, thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry, @glennjackman, the Broad Institute website (where I pulled the data from) has been acting funny lately (http://www.broadinstitute.org/ccle/), so I'm not surprised.

Answer (score 0):

use `grep -P` and your perl regexp
this is expramental and by the way you should have checked the man page
with `man grep`

Comment: you should have uploaded it to a file sharing site that you can just tell it a file from the web  it would have been faster only getting 500 kb per second

Comment: `grep IRX3 gene.res` outputs `4.791684        A       8.042779` for me

Comment: Well then it is OS X and its grep that is broken because it is all ok in linux. when I ran the command it was outputed to the screen. and by the way the terminal software in OS X runs bash or sh and just handles the I/O between bash/sh